# What is 'ax' in assembly?

Tags: assembly

I never really understood use of 'ax' in assembly.

I tried it, but I'm a newbie, and I'm getting lost.

```
mov ax, 10
mov ax, 20
```

I understand what mov does, however I need help with ax, and that stuff. I looked it up, and I couldn't find any help.

Comment: [check](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture)

Answer (score 0):

"ax" is one of 4 so-called general purpose registers with pre-defined names that can be used without declaration, which is why you see them in sample code. Other registers you are likely to see are:

- ax
- bx
- cx
- dx

See: http://www.csi.ucd.ie/staff/jcarthy/home/alp/alp1.html

Comment: To be correct, `ax` is a `16-bit` general purpose register in `8086 Assembly`. In `32-bit` (80368) assembly it is referred to as `eax` and `rax` in `x86_64`. It is addressable in 64, 32 & 16-bit language variants and is sub-divided into `high` and `low` bytes referenced as, `ah` and `al`, respectively.